# Permalinks and pagination are not working in WordPress with WP e-Commerce plugin

Tags: plugins, pagination, e-commerce, permalinks

I am running WordPress 3.2.1. and WP e-Commerce 3.8.7.2. The problems I am having are:

1. If the permalinks are set to default (`example.com/?p=123`) the e-Commerce plugin works ok except when I turn on pagination and enter 16 as the number of products to show per page, I can’t reach page 2 in the pagination links – it just brings me back to page 1 with the URI `example.com/?page_id=54&paged=2`. Same thing with the “Next” and “Last” links. How do I fix this?
2. If I go with better permalinks ( `/%category%/%postname%/` ) the store doesn’t work, the URI `example.com/category` leads to an empty page and none of the products work.
   Is there any way I could get the permalinks structure above and get the pagination to work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, though my initial product-page and categories are working fine, going to page 2 fails. Products-page give me an empty page and the categories give me unexpected, unthemed results.

The fix was to turn off ‘Use Hierarchical Product Category URL:’ in Settings/Store/General

See [this thread](http://getshopped.org/forums/topic/grid-view-pagination-not-working-on-page-2-onwards-2/) for background.